# Equivalent of CSS3's 'filter: grayscale(x)' with ImageMagick

Tags: css, imagemagick, grayscale

How can I apply the same effect of CSS3 'filter: grayscale' percentage with imagemagick ?
With -colorspace gray, it's the same as grayscale(100%), I cannot find how to change the percent.

I think maybe overlay the grayscale version with the original with a percentage but I cannot find how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Modified Answer**

What you are doing is essentially partially desaturating the input image. You can do this with the `-modulate` function in ImageMagick which converts each pixel into the HSL (Hue Saturation and Lightness) colourspace and lets you specify a percentage multiplier for each parameter. So, you can achieve the same sort of thing by reducing the Saturation, which is the second parameter, to 30 like this:

```
convert input.jpg -modulate 100,30 output.jpg
```

**Original Accepted Answer**

I think you need this:

```
convert image.jpg                \
  \( +clone -colorspace gray \)  \
  -define compose:args=70% -compose blend -composite out.jpg
```

It takes the original image and creates a clone of it. The clone is then set to greyscale and the blending percentage is set to 70. The two images are then blended and the result saved as `out.jpg`. Of course you can change the percentage as you wish.

It will convert this

[image]

into this

[image]

Comment: Exactly ! I tried the same king of command but the define and the blend did the trick, I missed it. Thanks !

Comment: I'm not at my Mac any more but there's probably a way of multiplying the Saturation by 0.3 - something like `convert input.jpg -colorspace HSL -channel S -evaluate multiply 0.3 +channel -colorspace sRGB output.jpg`